# Search input focus() function with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, onfocus

I want to make a search box when user focus on input field, background of submit button will be changed. Please can you help me to do this. Thank you in advance.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#bigsboxh").focus(function(){
        $("submit#bigsboxhsub").css({"background-color": "#137ff3"", "opacity": "1"});
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" id="bigsboxh" name="s" placeholder="search"/>
<button type="submit" id="bigsboxhsub"><i class ="fal fa-search"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have unnecessary quotes `"#137ff3""`.
2. Use only the `id` and not also the tag name  `$("#bigsboxh")`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bigsboxh").focus(function(){
        $("#bigsboxhsub").css({"background-color": "#137ff3", 'opacity':'1'});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="bigsboxh" name="s" placeholder="search"/>
<button type="submit" id="bigsboxhsub"><i class ="fal fa-search"></i>try </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using css

See code snippet

```css
#bigsboxh:focus + #bigsboxhsub{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="bigsboxh" name="s" placeholder="search"/>
<button type="submit" id="bigsboxhsub"><i class ="fal fa-search"></i>submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You placed extra Quotation mark`"#137ff3""` also

instead of `$("input#bigsboxh")` , `$("submit#bigsboxhsub")` only use id's `$("#bigsboxh")`,`$("#bigsboxhsub")`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bigsboxh").focus(function(){
        $("#bigsboxhsub").css({"background-color":"#137ff3", "opacity":1});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="bigsboxh" name="s" placeholder="search"/>
<button type="submit" id="bigsboxhsub"><i class ="fal fa-search">Search</i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code.

```
$("#bigsboxh").focus(function(){
       $("#bigsboxhsub").css('background-color', '#137ff3');

  }).blur(function(){
       $("#bigsboxhsub").css('background-color', 'FFFFFF');
  });
```